# a strange error in IE8 when connecting to my site remotely

Tags: https, error, bugs, internet-explorer-8

I'll explain.

I ran tests on my website at webpagetest.org and when I use IE8 on that site in Dulles VA, The website and ads load fine. I then made a test from Singapore because from other tools, it takes longer for Singapore to connect to my site. What's really strange is that adsense ads never load from the Singapore location. Instead I get red lines in the waterfall with error code 12157.

This URL shows what I mean:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160403_K9_788/

Is there anything I can do from a webmaster point of view (such as modifying HTTP headers and/or HTML code) to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

And it just gets even worse now. I made an update on my mobile site to load all site images after the ad begins loading. Various tests show successful results, however this particular test with IE8 from singapore keeps failing! In fact, right at the point where IE8 requests the ads, it stops and requests nothing more. very strange.

See: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160405_R6_1JG7/

Answer (score 2):

In attempting to connect to googlesyndication.com over HTTPS, IE failed to load the SSL libraries in the browser required to make the connection. The HTTP connection was successful, returning status 200, but the HTTPS connections failed. Microsoft explains the error as such:

> **ERROR_INTERNET_SECURITY_CHANNEL_ERROR**
>             12157
>             The application experienced an internal error loading the SSL libraries.

<sup>Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385465.aspx</sup>

Comment: ok, so then what can I do as a webmaster to rectify this? It would be sad if I have to tell clients using IE8 to switch web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

IE (any version, but particularly 8) is one of the worst browsers ever made, and no one should be using it. There are an endless # of issues you will face with it, when developing. I don't support it, and I have no problems telling my customers that. You would be doing them a favor or a major disservice if you didn't convince them to update.

Comment: I could say the same with IE 3 through 7 and other software, but heck, if there can be workarounds to things, all the better. It is unfair for people to have to upgrade all the time just to see things right on web pages.

Comment: You could have your website running perfectly on every other browser out there, but something will always break in IE8. You know that saying, " There will always be that one."? Well, that's the one lol.